# Importing template vaadin lose java code reference

Tags: java, spring, vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin10

I have a JsModule in my vaadin project, so I want to add to my page another, I made this so:

```
<div><products-search id="products-search"></products-search></div>
```

It works but there is a problem, the template `products-search` is related to a java class, if I access directly the page `products-search` the java binding works, but including the page in another in this way it works partially indeed the layout is visibile but doesn't work the interaction with the java code!

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

If you're importing a custom JS module to your template, the JavaScript code won't know anything about the imported web component's Java companion class. You'll need another approach - you could use `@Id` binding instead or add a `<slot>` in your template and append the corresponding Java component on the server.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I do that?

Comment: Docs for using `<slot>` elements: https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/polymer-templates/tutorial-template-components-in-slot.html

Comment: Docs for using `@Id` binding: https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/polymer-templates/tutorial-template-components.html